# CMAKE: Include files not found with OBJECT

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I have now a working CMake project which use Qt5 includes.
Several parts of the project are compiled using

`add_library(myLib STATIC ${lib_src})`

I'm trying to make use of the OBJECT now, so I changed to

`add_library(myLib OBJECT ${lib_src})`

but, when compiling, I get the following error:

> QObject, no such file or directory <- is not able to find qt includes

Can somebody tell me how can I fix my project to use OBJECT?

P.S. extra details:
the project is hosted [here](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=digikam.git&a=tree&hb=a5395215a74a8b36f3bb6b8ab8ab66e38c5782ab):
the main CMake which make the executable is in the [app folder](http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=digikam.git&a=blob&h=f9d1b9d5c9fb7e3690351e9f426b9d25cb2a7c4d&hb=a5395215a74a8b36f3bb6b8ab8ab66e38c5782ab&f=app%2FCMakeLists.txt).

*baloowrap* lib is linked here in *digikamgui*, then *digikamgui* is linked into *digikam* executable and the `OBJECT` that I want to create is in `utilities/baloo` which contains the following:

```
set(baloowrap_SRCS baloowrap.cpp)
add_library(baloowrap STATIC ${baloowrap_SRCS})
target_link_libraries(baloowrap KF5::FileMetaData KF5::I18n)
```

Comment: Are you including "find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)" in your CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine with STATIC.

Comment: Could you please show your CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: please look for extra details in the main post

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe you need link Qt5::Core: target_link_libraries(baloowrap Qt5::Core KF5::FileMetaData KF5::I18n)

Comment: Another question: can you use SHARED instead of OBJECT? Anyway, here you have more info: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library

Comment: SHARED can't be really used, because of circular dependecies... the reason why I want to change to OBJECT is because all that static libs are linked into the executable, and generating static libs increased the compiling time by a lot... I know about that information, the questions is: what exactly do they mean by PRE_BUILD, PRE_LINK, POST_BUILD?

Comment: Well, the problem is a object library cannot be used by itself. You need add that object library to another library using the command 'add_library'.

Comment: Yes, I'm having this syntax: add_library(digikamgui STATIC ${libdigikamgui_SRCS} $<TARGET_OBJECTS:baloowrap>), but It fails before is being integrated, due to QObject not found...

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think TARGET_OBJECTS is used when you use OBJECT, not STATIC. Did you try link Qt5::Core? Is "target_link_libraries(baloowrap KF5::FileMetaData KF5::I18n)" necessary? Usually, you link your application once, and you don't need link libraries with other libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my particular case, the include directories were automatically generated by CMake when I used target_link_libraries(Qt5::Core).

When you use OBJECT, you can't link anything and the sources fail to find the relevant includes...

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

you can solve the QObject problem by adding:

```
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: You should get the same result using "find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)"

Comment: as you can see in CMakeFiles, a similar call is made in top level CMakeFiles.txt

Comment: Mmm. So strange. In my projects, I don't need to include both lines, only find_package. Anyway, I think you should put your answer as the right one.

Comment: I had the same problem when writing python bindings. In this case, I was using `add_library(MyPythonModule MODULE module.cpp)`, and it failed to find the <QObject> header. Howerver, the wrapped library itself was declared as `add_library(MyLibrary SHARED library.cpp)` and was able to find <QObject> without problem. Strange. Anyway, explicitly adding `include_directories(${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS})` also solved the problem in my case, despite the Qt doc saying that it shouldn't be necessary.